# Define a global Test Setup

Tags: robotframework

I need that all my test cases will perform a set of actions before the test is executed, to do so in `__init__.robot` I defined:

```
Test Setup        Global Test Setup
```

The code for *`Global Test Setup`* is in `__init__.robot`. The test execution will fail with:

**No keyword name 'Global Test Setup' found.**

Can I make this keyword available in all my robot files without adding resource declaration?
Can I define in init a global resource definition?

Comment: I think you can't. [Robot Framework - initialization files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files). From the guide: `"Notice that keywords used as setups and teardowns must be available in test case files where tests using them are. Defining keywords in the initialization file itself is not enough."`

Comment: It is hard to guess without showing the code, but sometimes it happens when you don't create valid .robot file - see if your syntax is correct (e.g. dont start *** keywords *** with space before ***)